# Macbook pro 2009 update not taking effect

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore

I downloaded the update for OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. I restarted when it told me, but the update did not take effect. When I manually rebooted, that didn't work either. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Updates section of the App Store, if the 10.10.3 update is fully downloaded, the "Update" button next to it should be replaced by a "Restart" button. Click it, then click "Restart" on the notification that'll come up in the upper right of the screen, and then a restart will happen and the update will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason an update appears to be stuck, even after following user24601's advice, then the next thing to try would be to download & run the standalone [OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) which contains all updates since 10.10.0 & usually will bring things back into line.